# Creating a closeable tab in Mono/GTK

Tags: mono, gtk#

I'm trying to create new GTK Notebook tabs that contain both a name (as a Label) and a close   button (as a Button with an Image) with the following code:

```
Label headerLabel = new Label();
headerLabel.Text = "Header";
HBox headerBox = new HBox();
Button closeBtn = new Button();
Image closeImg = new Image(Stock.Close, IconSize.Menu);

closeBtn.Image = closeImg;
closeBtn.Relief = ReliefStyle.None;

headerBox.Add(headerLabel);
headerBox.Add(closeBtn);
headerBox.ShowAll();

MyNotebook.AppendPage(childWidget, headerBox);
```

This seems to work just fine; however, the button is about 1.5 - 2 times the size is needs to be, so there is a lot of extra space around the image inside the button. Having looked at [remove inner border on gtk.Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383663/remove-inner-border-on-gtk-button) I now see that the culprit is the "inner-border" style property of the GtkButton, but (being new to GTK) I can't seem to figure out how to override its value.

Is there some method of doing this that I'm missing? I don't have any reservations about not using a Button/Image combination, so any more obvious suggestions are welcome.

Note: I have seen the suggestion in the linked question to use an EventBox, but I was not able to add the Relief and mouseover effects to that Widget.

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code of some well-written GTK app that has these kind of buttons? Gedit is a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck. I just made the *exact same thing* yesterday, and can fortunately give you some code. The trick is to create a **Custom Tab Widget**.

```
public class MultiTab : Gtk.Box
{
    public Gtk.Label Caption;
    Gtk.Image img = new Gtk.Image(Platform.IMG + "tab_close.ico");
    public Gtk.ToolButton Close;
    public Gtk.Notebook _parent;
    
    public MultiTab ( string name )
    {
        CreateUI(name);
    }
    
    public MultiTab(string name, Gtk.Notebook parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
        CreateUI(name);
        CreateHandlers();
    }
    
    void CreateUI(string name)
    {
        Caption = new Gtk.Label(name);
        Close = new Gtk.ToolButton(img,"");
        PackStart( Caption );
        PackStart( Close );
        ShowAll();
        Close.Hide();
    }
    
    void CreateHandlers()
    {
        Close.Clicked +=  delegate {
            _parent.RemovePage(_parent.CurrentPage);
        };
    }
    
    public bool Active;
    
}
```

Next all you have to do is use this widget(or a similar one created by you) in Gtk.Notebook like this:

```
   MyNoteBook.AppendPage(new <YourPage>(), new MultiTab("<your caption>",this));
```

And You're done.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Program with Close-able Tab]

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
RcStyle rcStyle = new RcStyle ();
rcStyle.Xthickness = 0;
rcStyle.Ythickness = 0;
closeBtn.ModifyStyle (rcStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add items to box using Gtk.Box.PackStart/PackEnd methods rather than generic Gtk.Container.Add method. PackStart/PackEnd will allow you control how child widgets will be allocated space:

```
headerBox.PackStart (headerLabel, true, true, 0);
headerBox.PackEnd (closeBtn, false, false, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but using PackStart/PackEnd doesn't seem to change anything; the button takes up the same amount of space as when I used Add. From what I have read, I think the problem is related to the default inner-border size of GtkButtons.